# How to use "date" to print tomorrow's day of the week

Tags: linux, cron, date

On CentOS 6 Linux I use `date +%a` in several cronjobs and scripts to generate logfile names like `myprog-Tue.txt` and this works well for me since many years.

But now for one program I need to delete the previous logfiles, i.e. in my cronjob before I start my program and redirect its output to `myprog-Tue.txt`, I'd like to delete the `myprog-Wed.txt`.

This way I'd like to get the old logfiles out of my way, but still have 5-6 days of logfiles around.

So I have tried:

```
# date -v+1d +%a
date: invalid option -- 'v'
Try `date --help' for more information.
```

Does anybody know what's wrong here please?

Comment: You may want to post your Linux questions here:  http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @JasonEnochs There is nothing against posting Linux questions here on SuperUser, even though a more specialized site exists. (Same for [unix.se] and Ask Ubuntu.) **Alexander**, whatever you do, do *not* simply post the same question on multiple sites in the network. If you want your question migrated to a different site, "flag" it for moderator attention using the custom reason option, ask for migration, and the moderators will take a look and take appropriate action.

Comment: IMHO this is a bad idea to have the name-of-week. what if you have two weeks of logs? what if you restart during the day. At best both scenarios above would be confusing, at worst you'd (possibly) overwrite the existing file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would do that like this:

```
date -d "+1 days" +%a
```

That renders:

Sat

Answer (score 11):

The problem is not how you can use `date` to output what you want... your problem is:

> This way **I'd like to get the old logfiles out of my way, but still have 5-6 days of logfiles around**.

So, why not using `find` to remove all files but this week's?

```
find /path/to/files/ -mtime +7 -exec rm {} \;
```

---

In addition, `date` has many different implementations - I remember the last time I used it it was kind of hard to find the right `flags` to do what I wanted...  and it was not easy to make it work the same way between a Linux and an AIX machine... so, just in case this comment helps you to decide against `date` :)

Comment: +1 for solving the problem and not just answering the question :)

Comment: Yes, thanks - I use similar "find/xargs" commands elsewere too. But in this case I don't want to rely on "mtime", because I sometimes edit/look at the logfiles with "vi".

Comment: @AlexanderFarber this shouldn't change mtime unless you save the file. Were you perhaps thinking of atime? Also, maybe you should use `view` instead of `vi`, `view` opens readonly by default.

Comment: This might help to understand `atime`, `mtime`, and `ctime`: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/91200/74190.  Also, Ext4 and other file systems seem to store the creation date for the files - maybe that's something you can take advantage of (if using any of those filesystems, though).

Comment: @jim BTW: +1 for AIX... I was stuck using it years ago. Also, since this is Linux, you can rely on the `-delete` operator for (GNU) find. You can replace the `| xargs rm {} \;` with `-delete` and not be stuck with quoting rules or -no-run-if-empty.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-d` option to specify a phrase:

```
date -d '+ 1 day' +%a
```

Answer (score 1):

Another entry for "how to sanely manage your log files"....

You can look at [logrotate](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html) which should be part of most Linux distributions. It can manage deletion and compression. A lot of Linux daemons use this, so you can look at some example config files.

A bit simpler is [rotatelogs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/rotatelogs.html) which handles the rotation part, but doesn't do any deletion (your `find ... -delete` would do that.